# Steam updated today (2012-02-08) and now Civ crashes on icon execute

Tags: civilization-5

Steam updated and restarted today. Now when i double click my Civ icon, i get this immediately.

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: This doesn't happen to me. Do you have any advanced settings in your Civ 5 desktop shortcut?

Comment: My desktop short cut was generated from the dialogue where you select DX9/DX11. I had right clicked on DX11 to create a DX11 icon.

Comment: Doesn't happen to me either, and no update. I'm using windows XP, Ati graphics cards, dx9 only I guess..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way i fix the problem was to open steam via the system tray icon.

Find Civ 5 and click the Play button. I noticed it performed another update and executed Civ successfully.

[image]

Civ icon also executes Civ successfully.

Comment: 796 hours, that's dedication!

Comment: lol, yes, it surprised me too. I thought of blurring it out as I wasn't trying to brag. I do have a life outside!